# Why do i keep getting "unreachable code" and how do i fix it?

Tags: java

So I'm doing this assignment for my Java class and I keep running into this error `"unreachable code"` and I can't find out how to fix this error or even why it is occurring. Please help!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int suit;
        int cardNumber;


        Random generator = new Random();


          suit = generator.nextInt (4)+1;;
            String suitString;
            switch (suit) {
                case 1:  suitString = "hearts!";
                         break;
                case 2:  suitString = "diamonds!";
                         break;
                case 3:  suitString = "clubs!";
                         break;
                case 4:  suitString = "spades!";
                         break;


         cardNumber = generator.nextInt (13) +1;; //unreachable code
            String cardNumberString;
            switch (cardNumber) {
                case 1: cardNumberString = "ace";
                    break;
                case 2: cardNumberString = "2";
                break;
                case 3: cardNumberString = "3";
                break;
                case 4: cardNumberString = "4";
                break;
                case 5: cardNumberString = "5";
                break;
                case 6: cardNumberString = "6";
                break;
                case 7: cardNumberString = "7";
                break;
                case 8: cardNumberString = "8";
                break;
                case 9: cardNumberString = "9";
                    break;
                case 10: cardNumberString = "10";
                break;
                case 11: cardNumberString = "11";
                break;
                case 12: cardNumberString = "12";
                break;
                case 13: cardNumberString = "13";
                break;
```

Comment: Consider where the code **is**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a closing bracket for the `switch` statement after your first `case 4`.  The next statement is after the `break` which means it is unreachable.

```
switch (suit) {
            case 1:  suitString = "hearts!";
                     break;
            case 2:  suitString = "diamonds!";
                     break;
            case 3:  suitString = "clubs!";
                     break;
            case 4:  suitString = "spades!";
                     break;
} // Need to close the switch statement
```

Comment: You beat me by a margin!!! +1

Comment: i would also add  `cardNumber = generator.nextInt (13) +1;;` has two `;` something you could clean up @BlakeWinters

Answer (score 2):

You have to close the brackets. After the `case 4` the `{` is not closed making the code unreachable.

```
switch (suit) {
            case 1:  suitString = "hearts!";
                     break;
            case 2:  suitString = "diamonds!";
                     break;
            case 3:  suitString = "clubs!";
                     break;
            case 4:  suitString = "spades!";
                     break;
} //Here
```